# common djngo code base for my website and use the business logic for REST API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have my existing django web application. Now i need to expose the crud with all business validation / logic as a REST Api. e.g validate the available stock in the region before accepting the order. Simply exposing the crud operation API would not validate the underlying business logic.

Did search on the forum about it and few suggested to make use of ViewSet for API and also django views. But i am still not convinced about the practicality of the solutions and how to use.

What is the best solution, if i want to use my django views for regular business web application and also use the same business logic to expose with REST API. Appreciate if one can suggest with code snippet.

Comment: Not sure to understand your question, where is storing your business logic? Normally, you will create a serializer for your API with DRF and in the serializer, we will validate by calling the business logic function when it is required and your API view will return error is needed or saving data

Comment: exactly, if i write my business logic in the validation of serializer, how do i make use of the serializer when dealing with my regular HTTP request to post the transation? so what i was thinking is creating a separate class that has all business logic and use the same call in serializer and in the regular django view to keep the same code base of business logic. Will that be a right approach ?

Comment: There are many ways to manage business logic. In Django, most devs put the business logic in the Model layers, with some code in services.py at top of the app directory precisely to not have this concern with business rules present in serializers while serializers are specific to a single interface.

Comment: With this architecture, serializers call business logic from services or managers, or models and just parse data and check the format of the data sent via RestApi.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I did some more research based on your answer and i found the Model Managers and Model Queryset is most suitable for the requirement as it gives great flexibility and scalability for business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to use the simplest way to create crud the generics are the most easy way, but APIView can help you to customize you snippet of code as you want.

I hope its help you

Comment: Thanks. I Understand the APIVIew usage to customize and the djangorestapi documentation are very well explained. What i do not undertand is how to use the APIView in regular django view and also the restapi with all my business logic.

Comment: i think, another way is to use @api_view decorator for function based view and put business logic in a separate class that i can use both in the function base view and in the serializer for validation

Comment: Yes, decorator of api_view is good for get, post, delete and etc. But the way that you can write shorter and reach the goal in your mind in vewset and APIview is much faster